# Log4j dinámico en websphere

Tags: java, log4j, websphere

Tengo una aplicación en `websphere`, en mi archivo de `log4j` tengo dos `appender` para información y error, esto genera dos archivos en:

> ```
>  - /mypath/info.log
>  - /mypath/error.log
> ```

Quiero cambiar la ruta del `log4j` dinámicamente en `websphere` sin crear otro `war`, es posible?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>▼ He aquí un procedimiento que puedes ejecutar, ya sea en un *servlet*, en un *listener*, etc.</sub>

➊ Con un cargador de clases:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

➋ Cargas los valores de tu archivo de configuración “original”:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"));
```

➌ Sobreescribes el valor de la propiedad deseada con la nueva ruta:

```
props.setProperty("log4j.appender.archivo.file", "/logs/otro.log");
```

➍ Configuras log4j ([`org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html)) con esta nueva configuración:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```